# ¿Cómo modificar los botones de paginación del plugin DataTables para JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Estoy usando el plugin de datatables para paginar unas tablas y uso la paginación simple, pero los botones me salen muy juntos sin separación

Código JS

```
$('#tablaAptitudCliente').DataTable({
                language: {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
                "bInfo": false,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "pageLength": 25,
                 pagingType: 'simple',
                 responsive: "true",
                dom: 'Bfrtilp',
                buttons: [{
                          extend: 'excelHtml5',
                          text: '<i class="bi bi-arrow-down"> Excel</i>',
                          titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                          className: 'btn btn-success',
                          title:  'Reporte'
                         }]
            });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El datatable tiene su libreria de CSS, revisa si la estas cargando, si la estas cargando puedes inspeccionar con el navegador y buscar la regla de CSS en el paginador para que la modifiques agregando un poco mas de margen